# Bibliography Style Last Name First Initial

Tags: bibtex

Hello: I am looking for a bibliography style file that will produce references in the following style for the journal "Production and Operations Management":

> Hayes, R. H., G. P. Pisano. 1996. Manufacturing strategy: At the intersection of two paradigm shifts. *Production and Operations Management*, 5 (1), 25-41.

Comment: Have you looked into running the `makebst` utility -- part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package -- to create a bespoke bibliography style from scratch? In addition, have you tried to contact the journal's editorial office to inquire whether they might be able to provide a ready-made bst file?

Comment: No I haven't looked into either one of those options. I will ask the journal first. Thank you!

Comment: Have you got a result? We have also created a little file for our submission, maybe it helps: https://github.com/Elypson/poms-journal-bst